# How to install Imagick or resolve issue

Tags: images

I am running Site on Wordpress latest version. when I do Site health Check it gives me following errors,

> The WordPress Hosting Team maintains a list of those modules, both recommended and required, in the team handbook (opens in a new tab).
>
> Warning The optional module, imagick, is not installed, or has been disabled.

I search and try to install but failed, I tried to install via SSH using
`@cheapreplicablades.com [~]# /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/pecl install imagick`

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>
> downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
> .....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
> ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/imagick/examples

I don't know what to do, if anyone know kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you dont have the required permissions to install this PHP extension. This is often the case when youre using shared hosting. The best option is to contact your hosting provider and ask them to install this php extension. However if they provide you with a cpanel dashboard you may be able to do it yourself, heres how:

1. Log into your cpanel[image: Cpanel Login]
2. Select your php version, usually under the software section of cpanel[image: Select PHP Version]
3. Select the imagick option and then your options should be saved[image: Select Imagick]

And that's the last step. If you don't have cPanel your best solution is to contact your hosting provider. If it is a self hosted server you will need to contact the server admin to install the php extension for you. I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks For your Reply, I have cpanel access but when in go to php selector then it dont show any options like select options imagick or unselect.

Comment: If that's the case you have to contact your hosting provider to install it for you. From the error message you sent it seems you don't have admin access to install into that folder. Good luck

Comment: can i give access ? i have access to WHM server or can i give permission from WHM?

Comment: If you have access to the root account then you can

Comment: did you know how to grant access ? really thanks for your reply !

Comment: Well if you have root access then you don't need to grant access, you just need to install the imagick extension. So if you SSH via root then you can, `ssh root@cheapreplicablades.com`. Alternatively you can  grant access to users in your WHM interface if you're an administrator see here. [link](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/the-whm-interface/the-whm-interface/#features).
Just be very careful when granting privileges as this can be a potential security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install imagick and reload Apache2.

On Debian/Ubuntu, do the following:

```
$ sudo apt install php-imagick
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

If you run the PHP-FPM service, you also need to restart PHP-FPM service for Apache.

There is a more extensive treatment, covering other environments (including cPanel), in the [WordPress.org support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-imagick-module-not-installed-or-disabled-message/).